# Can I automate changing Magic Mouse 2 settings in macOS?

Tags: macos, mouse, automation, preferences

I'm a regular user.I often need to leave only the left button of Magic Mouse 2 active ,now I do it in the usual way:I go to the system preferences,and disable unnecessary options It takes ten clicks.After a session where I only needed the left button, I again have to repeat ten clicks to return the previous canceled options ,which is a lot

I would love an example in the Automator or another solution to automate swapping preferences rather than having to graphically select each option when it’s time to toggle my preferences. Is this possible?

Comment: If you've done it, do you need to do it again? Are you regularly switching between this setting and another? It might be possible to find the preference keys used and then write a script that calls `defaults write`.

Comment: This is a very common request! Thank you for asking it. I can’t wait to hear some options to automate this switch - it will be useful trick to learn for me as well. I haven’t seen this problem solved yet.

Comment: Out of curiosity - in which circumstances such a need arises (only left button active).

Comment: When I play chess.